# Seeking Verification: MIPS Cache Set Update Analysis

Tags: caching, mips, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

I've been working on a MIPS cache problem and wanted to double-check my solution. Here's the breakdown:

Problem: Determining which sets of a direct-mapped data cache have been updated after executing a program on a 32-bit MIPS processor.

1. lui $t0, 0x12ff
2. lw St1, 0x1240 (St0)
3. lw $t2, 0x5aa4 ($t0)
4. lw $t3, 0x4248 ($t0)

I need to specify the set number, valid bit value, and tag value for each updated set.

My Solution:

1. Set 3:

   - Tag value: 0x25
   - Valid bit: 1
2. Set 21:

   - Tag value: 0x55
   - Valid bit: 1
3. Set 43:

   - Tag value: 0x6d
   - Valid bit: 1

Could someone verify if my solution is correct? I'm particularly unsure about the validity of the cache entries. Any insights or advice on how to approach similar problems in MIPS cache analysis would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think there's not enough information given to answer.  There's no standard MIPS cache architecture.  How many indexes or count of index bits?  How many elements/bytes in a cache block?